# Rstudio AMI linkDropbox() gives no link

Tags: amazon-ec2, rstudio

It is not the first time I use the Rstudio AMI from Louis Aslett on Amazon EC2, but this time the `linkDropbox()` function drives me crazy and I could not find any help on Google: it just doesn't give any link !

```
> linkDropbox()
Launching Dropbox client, please wait ...
Dropbox launched.  Please visit the following URL in your browser now to link the server to your Dropbox account:
isn't

waiting (please do this now or linking may fail) ...
```

I don't know what this `isn't` do here, but there should be a link. Any one has had the same problem?

**EDIT**

It appears that the function gets stucks into the loop and return:

```
"This computer isn't linked to any Dropbox account..."
```

Comment: this one is still a mystery... any answers out there

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I came up with was to launch a new instance from a previous working image/snapshot - obviously not ideal if your existing instance has many packages/versions you need, but I found when I created a new AMI from Louis Aslett's site (after having trouble re-starting an old instance and updating Dropbox), I could not replicate behavior from February 2018 (except by using a snapshot of that previously functioning AMI). I am writing this in September 2018, so it is possible that the AMI's on Aslett's site will be updated and this won't be a problem anymore.
Good luck, future readers...

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, and realized that the security settings for the instance didn't allow outbound traffic on my current IP. I updated my security settings, ran `unlinkDropbox()`, and then ran `linkDropbox()` again, and it worked this time.